# gerund vs possesive vs ... in this sentence?

Tags: word-choice, grammar, word-order

Which one sounds better or is correct?

I managed a number of challenging projects, such as / which included

(...)  designing new electronic devices

(...) the design of new electronic devices

(...)  new electronic devices design

Comment: Please never just ask “Which is correct?”  It shows no effort on your part, and gives us nothing to go on.  As [the Help Center says in its “How to ask a good question” section](http://english.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask):  **“Have you thoroughly searched for an answer before asking your question? Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you found and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and above all, it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer!”** Thank you.

Comment: On the contrary, if I say "which is correct?" is because I have searched and found several options, and I'm not sure about the best one.
This is not just a matter of rules but common usage, I'm not native and I'm asking about that.

Comment: If you give no background, show no research, then we don’t know what you’ve found.  And questions should help future visitors, not just you yourself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Especially if it's for a résumé, use the first one. It's straightforward, direct, incisive, and conveys action in a way that the other two options do not.

Comment: I agree. Turning your verbs into abstract nouns tends to diminish any sense of action or agency; using gerunds is preferable as a distinctly smaller step in that same direction. I think current résumé style permits actual active, finite verbs with human subjects, though, much the liveliest option: "I designed . . . I developed . . . I deployed."

Comment: Ditto. I once used a Harry Potter book as a text in a writing class; the students were amazed at how the author conveyed so much action with gerunds and active participles. There were an incredible number in every paragraph.

Comment: OK, thanks,  To make it clear I've added the introductory sentence, and the "such as" or "wich included" linking words.
Another option would be with past tenses.